# My prefix cooks, suffix tastes, infix steals, whole keeps your food

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

- My prefix cooks your food.
- My suffix tastes your food.
- My infix steals your food.
- My whole keeps your food.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The answer is PANTRY

> Prefix is PAN

> Suffix is TRY

> Infix is ANT

> Whole is PANTRY